# Given a directed graph, count the total number of paths of ANY length

Tags: graph-theory

Given a directed graph, how to count the total number of paths of **ANY** possible length in it?

I was able to compute the answer using the adjacency matrix $A$, in which the number of paths of the length $n$ is the sum of elements $A^n$. But I have to calculate all $A^n$ for all possible $n$.

So is there any easier way, without computing large sparse matrix multiplication?

Sample graph:

[image: sample graph]

Comment: This question has been asked on the CS theory SE: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20246/counting-the-number-of-simple-paths-in-undirected-graph

Comment: @bradhd This question specifically asks for directed graph.

Answer (score 2):

Is it specifically a DAG? If so, process nodes in topological order, keeping count of how many different paths end at each node.

Comment: It only says it's a directed graph. Could explain how to process nodes in more detail?

Comment: @Yul: If there's a cycle in the graph, then depending on your definitions there may be infinitely many paths. Since this is homework, I'll stick to giving the hint I already have. You need to do _some_ thinking for yourself.

Comment: thx for the explanation. Although it is a hw, I already computed the answer using adjacency matrix. I am just wondering if theres any easier way, e.g. an equation `f(n)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Henning's hint is really spot-on. There are no directed cycles. So this is a DAG. Now where does the graph "start"? It starts at node (1), correct? So updating the number of paths follows a recursive definition? How many paths of length one are there from node (1)? Count up the adjacencies.

Now count paths of length (2). To do this, how many adjacencies do each of (1)'s children have?

You really just traverse the thing like a tree and count.

Comment: I think I know your point. For each node `i` in the graph, iterate the length of path from 1 to `max(len(path from i))`, count the number of paths in each iteration. But this manual computation becomes extremely difficult when the graph becomes large. I am just wondering if theres an easier to do so?

Comment: Why not write code to do this? I'm sure a computer algebra system would help here.

Comment: @ml0105: I don't think what you suggest is the solution I was hinting at. I'm not proposing to split up the calculations for paths of different length. Just do once and for all: "there is 1 path ending at 1", "there are $1+1=2$ paths ending at 2", "there are $2+1=3$ paths ending at 3", "there are $2+1=3$ paths ending at 4" ... "there are $5+5+1=11$ paths ending at 8", etc. etc.